# Why does Entity Framework forget what's in the model for my database after a while?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure, entity-framework-5

Disclaimer/warning: I'm fairly new to .net, having just started working with it a year ago.

I have an MVC webapp using Entity Framework 5.0, .Net 4.6, and MVC 4.0, running on Azure. This app accesses two databases, both with EDMX files, and both living on the same Azure server. The connection strings for the databases are in the `web.config` as dev connections, but the Azure app has environment connection strings that override them.

Both EDMX files were generated by "Updating the Model from Database" (ie, database exists first and edmx is generated to match it). One EDMX file is in a second project in the same solution, and that project is a reference to my app. 
This EDMX file / model works fine. The second EDMX file is in the Models section of my app, and only represents three tables and a handful of stored procedures. I haven't touched this EDMX in a year and it's had intermittent problems for the past year where it will occasionally not be able to access the database, but can be fixed by restarting the app.

Recently, I've been making changes to the webapp (but still not changing that EDMX or the views/controllers accessing the model for that database), and now the app is having trouble accessing the database very frequently. When I restart, or change the connection string, it will start working again, but forgets the database after an hour or so.

It feels like the webapp is losing the connection to the database somehow. The connection string is good, the model is accurate, etc (because it works when the app is restarted).

Why is this happening with the one database and not the other? What can I do to fix it? I can't just keep restarting the app every hour.

Here are the two error messages I'm currently getting:

When I try to pull back the records in a table named [Database] (which EF has called Databas in the model)

```
Message: [InvalidOperationException: The entity type Databas is not part of the model for the current context.]
 System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.UpdateEntitySetMappingsForType(Type entityType):59
 System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType):13
 System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize():0
 System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Include(String path):0
 System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.Include(String path):21
 CVSupportPortal.Models.ViewModels.CloudAdminViewModel..ctor(Firm f):482
 CVSupportPortal.Areas.CVS.Controllers.FirmsController.Cloud(Int32 firmid):206
 (unknown).lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ):-1
 System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters):129
 System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters):0
 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41():0
 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult):0
 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass37+<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33():30
 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49():134
 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49():134
 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49():134
 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult):0
 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass25+<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20():23
 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult):0
```

And when I call a stored procedure:

```
Message: [InvalidOperationException: The type parameter 'CVSupportPortal.Models.EF.Database_Status_List_Result' in ExecuteFunction is incompatible with the type 'CloudDatabasesModel.Database_Status_List_Result' returned by the function. ]
 System.Data.Common.Utils.MetadataHelper.CheckFunctionImportReturnType[TElement](EdmType expectedEdmType, MetadataWorkspace workspace):46
 System.Data.Common.Utils.MetadataHelper.GetAndCheckFunctionImportReturnType[TElement](EdmFunction functionImport, Int32 resultSetIndex, MetadataWorkspace workspace):25
 System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction[TElement](String functionName, MergeOption mergeOption, ObjectParameter[] parameters):0
 CVSupportPortal.Models.EF.CloudDatabasesEntities.Database_Status_List():0
(unknown).lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ):-1
 System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters):129
 System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters):0
 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41():0
 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult):0
 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass37+<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33():30
 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49():134
 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49():134
 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49():134
 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49():134
 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult):0
 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass25+<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20():23
 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult):0
```

Comment: You keep saying things like "forgets the database". What does this mean? Do you have specific error messages, exception types, and/or anything concrete like that? We'll need more specific information to help you. Very generally, what you're seeing *shouldn't* happen but *could* for a great many different reasons (connections not being closed and hitting the pool limit, etc.). We just need more details, please.

Comment: Sorry... that was confusing. I'm adding the error messages to the main question now.

Comment: This probably sounds like a very silly thing but can you create a unit test that creates an instance of your first context, then an instance of your second context, then performs a query against every table from your first context, then every table from your second context, then reverse the order of queries from the first then the same with the second? There are some limitations in the Entity Framework runtime that you might be hitting but just rarely, for instance, entity names must be unique. I have an example here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/58d979ae22bc1165eb26

Comment: Thank you for the response. The table / stored proc names are all unique. It's so weird. The web app is currently breaking with those errors, but I can connect to the database through Management Studio fine. I can also get the web app to work just by refreshing the connection string. I'm currently looking for a way to catch the error and force a refresh of the connection and see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what the cause of the problem is, but I was guessing that Entity Framework was losing the connection to the database somehow, since the database was accessible for other locations, just not through Entity Framework after it had been running for a while. I found out that the DbContext class has a constructor that allows you to specify a connection string at instantiation. My solution was to try using this in the hopes that it would start a new connection to the database instead of attempting to use an old one.

It worked. I haven't had any interruptions since I started using this. Here is what I changed (my database is called CloudDatabases).

CloudDatabases.Context.cs

```
// Already present
public CloudDatabasesEntities()
    : base("name=CloudDatabasesEntities")
{
}

// Added this constructor
public CloudDatabasesEntities(string connStr)
    : base(connStr)
{
}
```

In classes where I need to instantiate a connection to the database:

```
// Old, normal way
var cdb = new CloudDatabaseEntitites();

// New, non-breaking way
var connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CloudDatabasesEntities"].ConnectionString.ToString();
var cdb = new CloudDatabaseEntitites(connStr);
```

Where my Web.config (or Azure environment variables) has a connection string defined as such:

```
// Web.config
<add name="CloudDatabasesEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/CloudDatabases.csdl|res://*/CloudDatabases.ssdl|res://*/CloudDatabases.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=████████████████████████████████;initial catalog=CloudDatabases;persist security info=True;user id=████████████;password=██████████████████████;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```